# Ошибка линковщика Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, компоновщик, macos, c++, apple

[image]

Здравствуйте, дорогие форумчане!

Пишу динамическую библиотеку под МАС ОС Mavericks 64-bit в среде разработки ХСоde. Начинаю отлаживать, и отладчик падает с такой ошибкой:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"CHttpFileStorage::Logout()", referenced from:
vtable for CHttpFileStorage in HttpFileStorage.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Помогите исправить ошибку! Уже пробовала и фреймворки разные отключать/подключать. Ничего не помогает. Может какие-то настройки должны быть особенные в проекте? Приложила скриншот настроек линковщика.

Comment: Не видя Ваш код, конечно, сразу не разберешься, но обычно такая ошибка означает, что линкер не нашел реализации тела этого метода. Посмотрите, как именно Вы линкуете, действительно имеется ли реализация, все ли собранные библиотеки собраны этим компилятором.

Comment: clang подсказывает, что нужно запустить с параметром -v, и он подскажет больше (скорее всего, место вызова).

Comment: @smallFish, реализация имеется. Если я вас правильно поняла, то я проверяла в свойствах проекта, чтобы везде стояло в сочетании с GNU++11 - libc++(LLVM with support C++11).

Comment: @KoVadim, вы имелии ввиду запуск через терминал? Я просто новичок в программировании на MAC и, соответственно, в среде разработки XCode...

Comment: Я обычно все компилирую в консоли. А с XCode работал только разок, и то, запустил, закрыл.

Comment: @Kristya, я имел ввиду, что Вам нужно проверить не настройки компилятора, а наличие реализации всех объектов. Если пользуетесь каким-то фреймворком - включите его в проект, чем-то сторонним - включите в проект и убедитесь, что они совместимы с выбранной Вами архитектурой и настройками, если дело в Вашей функции - убедитесь, что компилятор найдет ее тело.

Comment: Поскольку проблема с линковкой, имхо, самое простое - удалите все содержимое тела этого метода и проверьте, работает ли. Затем создайте пустой проект с единственным экспортируемым методом - этим, который при этом просто возвращает константу, не делая никаких вычислений - посмотрите, получится ли. Получится - постепенно "возвращайте" утраченное, чтобы найти то место, где Вы чем-то пользуетесь, тело чего компилятор не может найти.
Звучит долго, но часто за 10 минут можно найти проблему.

Comment: @smallFish, спасибо вам!))) я уже внизу написала, в чём же была проблема... Но на будущее обязательно учту ваши советы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Успешно! Это была глупейшая ошибка, но так как глаз замылился уже, не заметила.

Неверный код:

```
UInt32 Logout(void)
{
    cout << " " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Верный код:

```
UInt32 HttpClass::Logout(void)
{
    cout << " " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо вам за поддержку и советы!)))
P.S.: когда кажется, что уже всё проверено... лучше проверить ещё раз))))

Comment: Вот, проверить - это я и говорил. =Р

Comment: Я была абсолютно уверена, что там всё хорошо!)))) Вот и такое бывает...))))